# Element position with respect to viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to calculate an element's position with respect to viewport(above, below or in viewport) :

```
    var viewportBottom = function () {
            return window.pageYOffset;
        },
        viewportTop = function () {
            return window.pageYOffset - window.innerHeight;
        },
        elementTop = function ($e) {
            return $e.offset().top - $e.height();
        },
        elementBottom = function ($e) {
            return elementTop($e) + $e.height();
        };


var aboveViewport = viewportTop() > elementBottom(this.$e),
        belowViewport = viewportBottom() < elementTop(this.$e),
        inViewport = !aboveViewport && !belowViewport;
```

This calculates correctly only as long as the element's height is same as viewport.
What am i missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This api worked for me : [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), 
It is specifically provided for evaluating the position with respect to viewport.

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
var container     = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    aboveViewport = (container.top  + container.height) < 0 ,
    belowViewport = container.top > $(window).height(),
    inViewport    = !aboveViewport && !belowViewport,
```